# ASP.NET - Returning multiple results

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to load news from my SQL Server database but I'm having an issue .

Index.aspx.cs :

```
public static string Load_News()
{
     string returnednews = "";
     SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Functions.ConnectionTag());

     try
     {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 3 * FROM website.dbo.news ORDER BY ui DESC", connection).ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                returnednews = string.Format("<div class='article'><div class=\"a_header\"> <div class='title' ><a href = '/articles/article.aspx?id={0}' ><i class='fa fa-feed' ></i>{1}</a></div></div><div class='a_body' ><div class='a_thumb' ><img src = '/img/news_thumb_1.jpg' /><hr>{4}<br/><font style='font -weight: 600; color: #8e44ad;'>{2}</font></div><div class='a_content' ><p>{3}</p></div></div><div class='a_footer'></div></div>", new object[] { reader["ui"], reader["title"], reader["poster"], reader["announcement"], reader["date"] });
            }
        }
        return returnednews;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return exception.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Index.aspx :

```
<%@ Page
Title="Website"
Language="C#"
MasterPageFile="~/wes.master"
AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="index.aspx.cs"
Inherits="index" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath='~/wes.master' %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">


 <div>
 <%=Load_News()%>
 </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Everything works perfectly and I get the results just fine however , It only gets 1 result from the database instead of 3 ? As you can see on the query , I'm selecting the three TOP news but I'm only getting one (query works on SQL Server without issues)

Comment: What if your table has only one record

Comment: It looks like you are overwriting `returnednews` in each iteration through the loop.  Perhaps you should be putting the rows into a contains (such as an array) or concatenating them together.

Comment: Oh right , I'm dumb .
It should be "returnednews += string.Format(" instead of returnednews = string.Format(... 
thank you :) and sorry , I don't know how I missed that

Comment: @GordonLinoff - You know `C#` as well ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you assign your variables to `returnednews` every iteration *again and again*, your `returnednews` will *only* have the last row values.

I think you need to some string concatenation for every values that your reader returns like;

```
returnednews += string.Format("<div class='article'>...
```

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and reader automatically instead of calling `Dispose` method manually.

Comment: Yes I know , idk how I could miss that . fixed